# Running shell script inside nodejs using shelljs

Tags: node.js, shell, environment-variables

I am trying to run a *shell script* inside `node.js` using `shelljs` module as follows.

```
exec('mycommand arg1')
```

where arg1 is supposed to be an Integer. When I replace arg1 with a number (let's say 8) it works perfectly but when I replace arg1 with a variable containing the corresponding value (in that case 8) i get an error with invalid argument.

I tried to  do some encoding but it doesn't seem to work. I don t know why. please help

Comment: Please, take a look at [how to format your posts properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just replaced the arg1 with your variable name, you'll have to concatenate your variable.

```
var myArg = 8;
exec('mycommand ' + myArg);
```

If you're using ES6, you can also make use of [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var myArg = 8;
exec(`mycommand ${myArg}`);
```